Get all revisions of an entry on front end / with twig
I'm basically trying to get what has been answered for this questions. This code doesn't seem to work any longer since it has been solved about 8 years ago.
Is there a way to get a list of all the revisions of an entry using twig? Further I would like to access the data of the revisions to show previous versions of an entry in the front end as well.

You can fetch the revisions of an element using the revisionOf() method on an element query.
{# @var entry craft\elements\Entry #}
{% if entry.hasRevisions() %}
    {% set revisions = craft.entries.revisionOf(entry).all() %}
    {% for revision in revisions %}
        {{ revision.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}


Great, thanks.
I guess it should be possible to access the data of the revision like this: craft.entries.revisionId( revId ).revisions( true ).one
Unfortunately I don't get any results. Any idea why this isn't working?

Maybe, that’s not what you asked though.
